# In ANALYSIS OF VARIANCE-Should we distinguish between independent and dependent variables?

Tags: anova

Do we need to differentiate which variable is independent or dependent when doing univariate analysis of variance to test whether the means are equal or not? Because, according to my understanding, the ANOVA test can be performed when the group variable is deemed an independent variable.

My colleague believes that as long as we have one continuous and one categorical variable, we can conduct an ANOVA to determine whether the means around the levels of  group/categorical variable are statistically distinct.

From my perspective, however, we must ensure that the group variable or categorical variable is independent variable. For example, if one variable is Cholesterol and the other one is BMI levels, then as clinically the Cholesterol  can affect BMI levels, so ANOVA can not be conducted here and simple logistic regression should be employed instead.

Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: Can you rule out that BMI affects cholesterol? In many situations, there are feedback loops, e.g. that overweight people eat a lot of what is not good for them because it gives them pleasure!

Comment: @
Nick Cox, Yes, you are right. I only provided this example to determine whether or not an ANOVA test can be performed if BMI groups are assumed to be dependent.

Comment: Another point, marginal to the question, but still relevant: If you have data on cholesterol and BMI, coarsening either to be grouped is highly undesirable, as throwing away information.

Comment: @Nick Cox, Actually, our initiative does not involve BMI or cholesterol. I just provided a random example for improved understading. Assuming that in one project, BMI levels are the response variable and age, sex, cholesterol, height, and weight are factors, can we execute the ANOVA test for each of these variables vs BMI levels by treating BMI levels as the dependent variable? I apologize if my example has confused you.

Comment: I don't feel confused, but I can't guess at your real focus unless you tell us. Yes, BMI could be the outcome for analysis of variance. I would find an equivalent regression as or more congenial myself.

Comment: @ 
Nick Cox, thanks so much for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Analysis of variance compares means and variability about those means of an outcome or response variable, given information on one more other variables, which are often, but not necessarily, categorical.

Whether you call that outcome *dependent* and the other variable(s) *independent* is a matter of taste. For other reasons, many statistical people find those terms overloaded and try to use more evocative terms. (It's not trivial that many beginners get muddled on which is which.)

How you -- or whether you can -- interpret the results in terms of causation, process, mechanism or whatever else is a key question, but I call it a different question.

Even in simple exercises the chain of causation and process can be hard to think about. If I compare say males and females on mathematics scores, that doesn't mean that I think or am hypothesising that anatomy or physiology determines or even influences mathematics scores. In the first instance I am checking to see if there are different means in statistical terms. If I find that there are different means, then I stop describing and have to wonder what else lies behind it, in this case quite possibly social or cultural or educational factors. If the example seems contentious, that is the point. We may need very detailed discussion of what is behind any pattern and it is usually the more difficult part of the analysis.

Crudely, both you and your colleague have good points, but your ways of looking at analysis of variance are just different.

Comment: @
Nick Cox
 , Many gratitude for your time and assistance. Consequently, can we conduct the anova analyses between selected variables and group variable followed by logistic regression (including all selected variables and group variable) in the same manner as the site listed below? https://padhokshaja.medium.com/using-anova-and-multinomial-logistic-regression-to-predict-human-activity-cd2101a5e8bf

Comment: I don't fully understand the extra question. Which variable has two distinct outcomes that you can code 0 and 1? If a group variable is one such, then logistic regression can follow. You're changing the question, but that can make sense.

Comment: I apologize if this causes confusion. Allow me to explain differently. My supervisor requested that the analysis be conducted in two stages. First, conduct the ANOVA tests (for approximately 20 continuous variables) and our group variable (for example, BMI level).

Comment: 2. then Employ a logistic regression with all of these continuous variables, with the group variable (BMI levels as the dependent variable). For my argument, if the BMI levels are the response variable, we should run single logistic regression including each single continuous variable and BMI level, followed by multiple logistic regression including all continuous variables. Because, as stated, I believe ANOVA can be utilized when the dependent variable has a continuous format

Comment: @ Nick Cox, To determine whether my supervisor's proposed method for conducting the analysis is correct or not, I searched Google and located the above link. In that link, they conducted ANOVA tests on 500 continuous variables vs one categorical variable (activity level), to identified the variables with  significant p-values, and then performed a logistic regression between Activity (as outcome) and the variables with significant p-values (based on ANOVA tests)

Comment: Your extra comments are morphing into a different question which I think you should ask separately.  Your supervisor should be part of this conversation. What is the goal of the analysis? The proposed strategy seems very roundabout;

Comment: thanks so much for your time and advice. Sure, I will make a different question.